# Not Exists in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, not-exists

I have the table(supplier) column(sup_status) contains  the value 'A' and 'I' and now i am selecting the value 'A' using not exists. But in real scenario the main query returns the sup_stauts 'A' and 'I' so I need to select the sup_status='A' records using not exists. But result is not coming. I do not want to use not in operator.

For Example

```
 SELECT SUP_STATUS FROM SUPPLIER

SUP_STATUS
    A
    I

    
    select sup_status from supplier where not exists(select 
    sup_status from supplier where sup_status='I')
```

**Desired Output**

```
  SUP_STATUS
     A


 MAIN QUERY where not exists(select sup_status from supplier
    where sup_status='I')
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output. Uncorrelated subquery in the `exists` predicate seems to be logically invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the query:

```sql
select sup_status
from   supplier
where  not exists(
         select sup_status
         from   supplier
         where  sup_status='I'
       )
```

Then the sub-query is not correlated to the outer query and so the sub-query is searching the table's entire result set to see if there is any row where the supplier status is `I`. If there exists one row within the entire result set then the query will output nothing.

If you want to correlate the sub-query to the outer query then you need to specify that in the query. For example, if you want to correlate on `supplier_name`:

```sql
select sup_status
from   supplier s
where  not exists(
         select sup_status
         from   supplier x
         where  x.sup_status='I'
         and    s.supplier_name = x.supplier_name
       )
```

You could also use analytic functions so that you do not have to use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT sup_status
FROM   (
  SELECT sup_status,
         COUNT(CASE sup_status WHEN 'I' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY supplier_name) AS has_i
  FROM   supplier
)
WHERE  has_i = 0;
```